# Как изменить элемент Label по id?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6, kivy

Нужно чтобы каждая кнопка меняла label под ней по id, как это реализовать?

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.app import runTouchApp
from kivy.uix.togglebutton import ToggleButton
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.gl=GridLayout(rows=20, cols=0, id='0')
        i=0
        while i < 10:
            self.btn = ToggleButton(text='Кнопка '+str(i),color=[0,0,0,1], id=str(i), group=i, on_press=self.pressed_btn, background_color=[1,1,1,1], background_normal='')
            self.gl.add_widget(self.btn)
            self.gl.add_widget(Label(text='Текст', id=str(i)))
            i+=1
        root = ScrollView(size_hint=(1, None), size=(Window.width, Window.height))
        root.add_widget(self.gl)
        runTouchApp(root)
    def pressed_btn(self, instance_toggle_button):
        if instance_toggle_button.state=='down':
            instance_toggle_button.background_color=[.40,.40,.40,1]
            instance_toggle_button.background_down=('')

MyApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.metrics import dp
from kivy.uix.togglebutton import ToggleButton
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label


class MyApp(App):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.gl = GridLayout(rows=20, cols=1, size_hint_y=None)
        self.gl.bind(minimum_height=self.gl.setter("height"))
        self.root = ScrollView()
        self.root.add_widget(self.gl)

    def build(self):
        for i in range(10):
            btn = ToggleButton(
                text="Кнопка " + str(i),
                color=[0, 0, 0, 1],
                group=i,
                background_color=[1, 1, 1, 1],
                background_normal="",
                size_hint_y=None,
                height=dp(36),
            )
            lbl = Label(text="Текст", size_hint_y=None, height=dp(36))
            self.gl.add_widget(btn)
            self.gl.add_widget(lbl)
            btn.bind(on_press=lambda args, x=lbl, y=btn: self.pressed_btn(x, y))

        return self.root

    def pressed_btn(self, lbl, btn):
        lbl.text = f"{lbl.text} {btn.text}"


MyApp().run()
```